# Select marker by clicking on a map and update selected input

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am currently working on a Shiny app and I encountered some problems. My objective is to display temperature graphs for specific weather stations and selected years. Users can choose a station name from the dropdown menu, but I would like to enhance the functionality by allowing users to click on a station marker on the map to update the selected station name in the dropdown menu([click to see the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFTX9.jpg)). I believe there might be an issue with the event handling or how I am accessing the clicked marker information. I have included a snippet of the relevant code below:

```r
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

geopackage_path <- "C:/Users/yagmur/work/Spain/data/"

year <- 2022
sf_data <- st_read(file.path(geopackage_path, paste0("meteo_andalucia_", 
                                                     year, ".gpkg")))

# Select unique locations
unique_locations <- sf_data %>% distinct(station_name, .keep_all = TRUE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 4,
           selectInput("station", "Select a Station", 
           choices = unique_locations$station_name),
           actionButton("compare", "Compare Temperature")
    ),
    column(width = 8,
           leafletOutput("map")
    )
  ),
  plotOutput("graph")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Initialize the selected station as NULL
  selected_station <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  # Render the leaflet map
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(data = unique_locations) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addCircleMarkers(radius = 4,
                       color = "red",
                       fillOpacity = 0.8,
                       label = ~station_name,
                       group = "markers")
  })
  
    
    # Update the selected station when a marker is clicked
    observeEvent(input$map_marker_click, {
      clicked_marker <- input$map_marker_click
      clicked_station <- clicked_marker$station_name
      selected_station(clicked_station)
      
      # Update the select input with the clicked station
      updateSelectInput(session, "station", selected = clicked_station)
    })
    
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would greatly appreciate your expert advice and any suggestions you may have to help me resolve this issue.

When a marker is clicked, the corresponding station name is extracted from the input$map_marker_click$station_name and stored in the selected_station reactive value using selected_station(clicked_station)

Based on the code, the expected behavior would be that when a user clicks on a marker on the Leaflet map, the corresponding station name should be displayed as the selected option in the select input.

Comment: I think if you add `layerId = ~station_name` to your `addCircleMarkers()` call, that should solve the problem.  Joe Cheng's intervention on [this thread](https://community.rstudio.com/t/click-on-leaflet-marker-and-get-info/11016/2) gives a bit more detail on the intended use.

Comment: You'll also have to change `clicked_station <- clicked_marker$station_name` to `clicked_station <- clicked_marker$id`

Comment: Hey @DaveArmstrong
Problem is solved, thanks a lot! I have another question: in this App, I want to display graphs for specific weather stations and selected years. I have a geopackage file from the years 2010-2022. and I need to load all the datas to plot the temperature comparison graph.  When I run the code, loading the App is extremely slow. Is there any trick for that? Here is how I load the data:
years <- 2010:2022
sf_data <- purrr::map_dfr(years, function(year) {
  st_read(file.path(geopackage_path, paste0("meteo_andalucia_", year, ".gpkg"))) %>%
    mutate(year = year)

Comment: A database (e.g., PostGIS) might be a better approach so you only have to read in what you need when you need it.  Another option would be to save the data as an .rds file it may make loading all the data quicker.